# PHP mail function not working - sendmail to blame?

Tags: centos, email, sendmail

All of a sudden it appears as though we can no longer send E-Mail by using the mail function in PHP. After doing some investigation through looking at other threads in ServerFault and on various other sites I seem to have determined that sendmail is to blame.

I'm getting this error when I try to reboot it's service.

> /etc/init.d/sendmail restart Shutting down sm-client: [  OK  ]
>   Shutting down sendmail: [FAILED] Starting sendmail: 554 5.3.5
>   /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 261: service "smtp" unknown: Permission
>   denied [FAILED] Starting sm-client: [  OK  ]

I've already tried reinstalling it (yum remove sendmail, yum install sendmail) to no avail.
I'm also seeing the following in our /var/log/maillog

> Mar 31 03:22:19 xxxxxxxx sendmail[2909]: r2VAMJO9002909:
>   to=xxxxxxxxxxxx, ctladdr=nobody (99/99), delay=00:00:00,
>   xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30263, relay=[127.0.0.1]
>   [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by
>   [127.0.0.1]

Comment: It seems that smtp is not declared in your `/etc/services`. What is the output of grep smtp /etc/services

Comment: Duplicate the problem again and report the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc`

Comment: smtp            25/tcp          mail
smtp            25/udp          mail
urd             465/tcp         smtps   # URL Rendesvous Directory for SSM / SMTP over SSL (TLS)
rsmtp           2390/tcp                # RSMTP
rsmtp           2390/udp                # RSMTP